# Generating an X.509 certificate filled with raw data in Java

Tags: java, security, x509

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is making a private key/public certificate pair in order to export it to a pkcs12 repo. Certificate fields are to be populated with data that a user inserts through standard input or a GUI. This is a problem because I've only been able to find ways of loading an existing certificate and getting its v3 extensions, but not setting them. Additionaly, I would like to avoid using any external libraries such as BouncyCastle.

So far I've been able to produce a certificate using sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen class and X500Name object but I haven't found any method for feeding it an E-mail info since the X500Name doesn't have an appropriate constructor, as well as version 3 extensions (specifically basic constraints, alternative issuer name and key usage).

On the other hand, I have been looking into java.security.cert.CertificateFactory and its generateCertificate() method. It expects an InputStream of a base64 encoded existing certificate as an argument. So, to fullfill my requirements of generating a certificate and not loading an existing one, I've found a way of getting an InputStream from a String:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

I know that this string should begin with BEGIN CERTIFICATE and end with END CERTIFICATE to mimic an actual certificate but I don't know how to generate it from raw data.

So, to summarize my question: Is there a way to programatically populate an empty X.509 certificate with fields including e-mail and v3 extensions without using external libraries such as BouncyCastle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the doc on java.security.cert.CertificateFactory again, it says it **can be base64 encoded** but then it must be in PEM format ( -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- /  -----END CERTIFICATE-----). You can also use DER format.

Comment: I may have put that sentence badly. I do understand that formats can vary and that encoding means something else, but the question is how to generate a String like that using parameters obtained from a standard input (and put into variables in Java code) in order to pass its InputStream as an argument for generateCertificate(). I don't know how to explain it better, I'm trying to fool the generateCertificate() method into thinking that it generates a certificate object from an existing certificate from a pkcs12 repo, so I can put it into a pkcs12 repo.

Comment: Have you tried to call getEncoded() on the returned certificate? It returns the cert in DER format.